# GameCharacter stucks in jumping position after detecting platform in a simple platform game javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a small, simple platform game in javascript and have a problem with implementing platforms in it. My game character is jumping properly, but when it detects a platform that he should jump on, he just floats a few pixels above it in "jumping position" and stays there. It is possible to move to both sides with arrows and to "slide" back to the ground. I assume that there is some issue with a conditional statement that serves "falling", but I can't really find it.

The code is shortened, was way too long in an original version (added game character function):

```js
var gameChar_x;
var gameChar_y;
var floorPos_y;
var scrollPos;
var gameChar_world_x;

var isLeft;
var isRight;
var isFalling;
var isPlummeting;

var trees_x;
var treePos_y;
var collectables;

var game_score;
var ice_cream_store;
var lives;

var platforms;

var gameSound;
var jumpSound;
var gameOverSound;



function preload() {
  soundFormats('mp3', 'wav');

  //load game sound 
  gameSound = loadSound('assets/Frozen.mp3');
  gameSound.setVolume(0.03);
  //load jump sounds here
  jumpSound = loadSound('assets/jumpSnow.wav');
  jumpSound.setVolume(0.1);
  //load game over sound
  gameOverSound = loadSound('assets/gameOver.mp3');
  gameOverSound.setVolume(0.1);

}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(1024, 576);

  startGame();
  gameSound.play()

  floorPos_y = (height * 3) / 4;
  gameChar_x = width / 2;
  gameChar_y = floorPos_y;
  treePos_y = 282;

  // Variable to control the background scrolling.
  scrollPos = 0;

  // Variable to store the real position of the gameChar in the game
  // world. Needed for collision detection.
  gameChar_world_x = gameChar_x - scrollPos;

  // Boolean variables to control the movement of the game character.
  isLeft = false;
  isRight = false;
  isFalling = false;
  isPlummeting = false;
  game_score = 0;
  lives = 3;

  // Initialise arrays of scenery objects.

  platforms = [];
  platforms.push(createPlatforms(150, floorPos_y - 80, 150));
  platforms.push(createPlatforms(550, floorPos_y - 80, 100));
  platforms.push(createPlatforms(750, floorPos_y - 80, 50));

}

function draw() {
  background(100, 155, 255); // fill the sky blue

  noStroke();
  fill(240, 240, 240);
  rect(0, floorPos_y, width, height / 4); // draw snow on the ground

  push();
  translate(scrollPos, 0);
  // Draw clouds.
  drawClouds();

  // Draw mountains.
  drawMountains();

  // Draw trees.
  drawTrees();
  // Draw canyons.
  for (var i = 0; i < canyons.length; i++) {
    drawCanyon(canyons[i]);
    checkCanyon(canyons[i]);
  }

  // Draw collectable items.
  for (var i = 0; i < collectables.length; i++) {
    if (collectables[i].isFound == false) {
      drawCollectable(collectables[i]);
      checkCollectable(collectables[i]);
    }
  }

  //draw platforms
  for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
    platforms[i].draw();
  }

  renderIcecreamStore();
  checkPlayerDie();

  pop();

  // Draw game character.

  drawGameChar();

  //game score and lives
  fill(255);
  stroke(0);
  textFont("fantasy");
  textSize(18);
  text("Score:" + game_score, 100, 40);
  text("Lives:" + lives, 100, 60);

  if (lives == 0) {
    fill("red");
    textSize(30);
    text("Game Over . Press space to continue", width / 4, height / 2);
    lives = 0;
    drawGameChar();
    return;

  }
  if (ice_cream_store.isReached == true) {
    fill("red");
    textSize(30);
    text("Level Complete. Press space to continue", width / 4, height / 2);
    return;
  }
  //Logic to make the game character move or the background scroll.

  if (isLeft) {
    if (gameChar_x > width * 0.2) {
      gameChar_x -= 10;
    } else {
      scrollPos += 10;
    }
  }
  if (isRight) {
    if (gameChar_x < width * 0.8) {
      gameChar_x += 10;
    } else {
      scrollPos -= 10; // negative for moving against the background
    }
  }

  // Logic to make the game character rise and fall.
  //jumping
  if (gameChar_y < floorPos_y) {
    var isContact = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
      if (platforms[i].checkContact(gameChar_world_x, gameChar_y) == true) {
        isContact = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isContact == false) {
      gameChar_y += 2;
      isFalling = true;
    }
  } else {
    isFalling = false;
  }
  //checking final point
  if (ice_cream_store.isReached == false) {
    checkIcecream_store();
  }

  // Update real position of gameChar for collision detection.
  gameChar_world_x = gameChar_x - scrollPos;
}

// ---------------------
// Key control functions
// ---------------------

function keyPressed() {
  console.log(keyCode);
  if (keyCode == 37) {

    isLeft = true;

  }
  if (keyCode == 39) {

    isRight = true;

  }
  if (keyCode == 32) {

    if (!isFalling) {
      gameChar_y -= 100;
      jumpSound.play();
    }
  }
}

function keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == 37) {
    isLeft = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == 39) {
    isRight = false;
  }
}

// ------------------------------
// Game character render function
// ------------------------------

// Function to draw the game character.

function drawGameChar() {
  // draw game character
  if (isLeft && isFalling) {
    // add your jumping-left code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 6, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 14, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 31, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 46, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 27, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x - 3, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 56, gameChar_x - 3, gameChar_y - 62);
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 63);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x - 6, gameChar_y - 30, gameChar_x - 20, gameChar_y - 35);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 13,
      gameChar_y - 47,
      gameChar_x - 23,
      gameChar_y - 40,
      gameChar_x - 13,
      gameChar_y - 43
    );
  } else if (isRight && isFalling) {
    // add your jumping-right code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 6, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 14, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 31, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 46, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 27, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x + 3, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 56, gameChar_x + 3, gameChar_y - 62);
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 63);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x + 6, gameChar_y - 30, gameChar_x + 20, gameChar_y - 35);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x + 13,
      gameChar_y - 47,
      gameChar_x + 23,
      gameChar_y - 40,
      gameChar_x + 13,
      gameChar_y - 43
    );
  } else if (isLeft) {
    // add your walking left code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 4, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 15);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 6,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x - 17,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x - 6,
      gameChar_y - 36
    );
  } else if (isRight) {
    // add your walking right code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 4, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 15);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x + 6,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x + 17,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x + 6,
      gameChar_y - 36
    );
  } else if (isFalling || isPlummeting) {
    // add your jumping facing forwards code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 23, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 13, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 13, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 36, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 50, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 33, 3, 3);
    //eyes
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 52, 2, 2);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 52, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 61, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 66);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 59, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 66);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 61, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 66);
    //arms
    line(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 37, gameChar_x - 15, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 37, gameChar_x + 15, gameChar_y - 57);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 2,
      gameChar_y - 49,
      gameChar_x - 10,
      gameChar_y - 43,
      gameChar_x + 2,
      gameChar_y - 49
    );
  } else {
    // add your standing front facing code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eyes
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arms
    line(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x - 15, gameChar_y - 17);
    line(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x + 15, gameChar_y - 17);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 2,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x - 10,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x + 2,
      gameChar_y - 39
    );
  }
}

// ---------------------------
// Background render functions
// ---------------------------

// Function to draw cloud objects.


// Function to draw mountains objects.

// Function to draw trees objects.


// ---------------------------------
// Canyon render and check functions
// ---------------------------------

// Function to draw canyon objects.

function drawCanyon(t_canyon) {
  fill(99);
  rect(t_canyon.x_pos, floorPos_y, t_canyon.width, height);
  fill(70);
  rect(t_canyon.x_pos + 10, floorPos_y, t_canyon.width - 20, height);
  //water
  fill(123, 193, 239);
  rect(t_canyon.x_pos + 10, floorPos_y + 80, t_canyon.width - 20, height / 4);
}

// Function to check character is over a canyon.

function checkCanyon(t_canyon) {

  if (
    gameChar_world_x > t_canyon.x_pos &&
    gameChar_world_x < t_canyon.x_pos + t_canyon.width && gameChar_y >= floorPos_y
  ) {
    //    console.log('true')
    isPlummeting = true;
    console.log(gameChar_y)
    var helpvar = 4;
    gameChar_y += helpvar;

  } else {
    isPlummeting = false;

  }
}
// ----------------------------------
// Collectable items render and check functions
// ----------------------------------

// Function to draw collectable objects.

function drawCollectable(t_collectable) {
  fill(255, 223, 128);
  noStroke();
  triangle(
    t_collectable.x_pos,
    t_collectable.y_pos,
    t_collectable.x_pos - 8,
    t_collectable.y_pos - 30,
    t_collectable.x_pos + 8,
    t_collectable.y_pos - 30
  );
  fill(165, 23, 105);
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(1);
  ellipse(t_collectable.x_pos, t_collectable.y_pos - 35, 20);
  fill(247, 196, 225);
  ellipse(t_collectable.x_pos, t_collectable.y_pos - 45, 18);
}

// Function to check character has collected an item.

function checkCollectable(t_collectable) {
  if (
    dist(
      gameChar_world_x,
      gameChar_y,
      t_collectable.x_pos,
      t_collectable.y_pos
    ) < 50
  ) {
    t_collectable.isFound = true;
    game_score += 1;
  }
}

//drawing final point

//Function to check character has reached final point

//Checking if character felt into the canyon
function checkPlayerDie() {
  if (gameChar_y == height) {
    console.log('died')
    lives -= 1
    if (lives > 0) {
      startGame()
    } else if (lives == 0) {
      gameOver()
      gameSound.stop();
    }
  }
}
//CREATE PLATFORMS
function createPlatforms(x, y, length) {

  var p = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    length: length,
    draw: function() {
      noStroke();
      fill(205, 230, 255);
      rect(this.x, this.y, this.length, 20)
    },
    checkContact: function(gc_x, gc_y) {
      if (gc_x > this.x && gc_x < this.x + this.length) {
        var d = this.y - gc_y;
        if (d >= 0 && d < 2) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
  return p;
}

function startGame() {
  gameChar_x = width / 2;
  gameChar_y = floorPos_y;
}

function gameOver() {

  gameChar_x = width / 2;
  gameChar_y = floorPos_y - 50;
  gameOverSound.play();


}
```

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: You haven't included your `drawGameChar` function definition, which is probably where your issue is

Comment: I've just cut it off from the code for the purpose of this question only - it was way too long. So that's not an issue, unfortunately...

Comment: Ok, so you need to find out if `isFalling` is set correctly. If it is, your issue is inside `drawGameChar`, which we can't help you with since you haven't shared the code

Comment: what about the `checkContact` function? Does it ever return true?

Comment: I've added a game character drawing function - but it looks that a problem is not within it.

Comment: ''checkContact'' returnes true all the time the game character is floating above the platform - checked with console.log

Comment: Are you resetting `isFalling` to false after contact? Check all your `is...` conditions

Comment: And does it return false when the character is below the platform?

Comment: When the game character is above the platform, isContact is switching from true to false in the loop. When the game char is under the platform or up on the sides (but not onto) it is set to false.

Comment: `When the game character is above the platform, isContact is switching from true to false in the loop.` shouldn't this switch to true when you're on top of the platform? and what about `isFalling`? this controls the drawing, so if you do not reset it it stays in the falling position.

Comment: Yes, it should, I just don't know how to fix it - I saw in the console that it is switching in a loop all the time and I really don't know why. I also do not know why it stays a few pixels above platforms instead of on the platform.

Comment: Well, the reason you see it called a lot is because the main function `draw()` is probably called several times a second. Each time, when on top of a platform, the char_y is less than floor_y so you check if the character is in contact with any platform. You need to log `isContact` and `isFalling` at the end of `draw()` and also in the section `Logic to make the game character rise and fall`.

Comment: I actually maybe see the problem - isContact is not set permanently to true on the platform, but keeps switching, and each time it goes to "false" "isFalling" is activating. I've tried to write else if statement to the section "// Logic to make the game character rise and fall.
     //jumping" but it didn't help. What I do not understand is why a game character floats a few pixels above platforms. And of course, I still do not know how to fix a problem with isContact statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. There was missing `isFalling=false` `

```
     for(var i=0; i<platforms.length; i++){
         if(platforms[i].checkContact(gameChar_world_x, gameChar_y)==true){
             isContact=true;
             isFalling=false;
             break;`
```

Now it works beautifully. Thanks for all suggestions!